# How do you JOIN two MySQL tables where the data is NOT in the other table?

Tags: mysql, join

For example, I have a pet table and a lost pets table. I want to get all of the pets that are NOT lost with 1 join and no sub-selects. Is that possible? A typical join only returns results that are in both tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're describing an OUTER JOIN as compared to a standard INNER JOIN. Google or check your documentation - I'm sure you'll find lots of examples. :)

SELECT * FROM pets AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN lost-pets AS lp
    ON p.name = lp.name
WHERE lp.id IS NULL

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT PETS.NAME
FROM PETS
   LEFT OUTER JOIN LOST_PETS
     ON PETS.PET_ID = LOST_PETS.PET_ID
WHERE LOST_PETS.PET_ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, yes, say :

```
SELECT *
FROM pets LEFT OUTER JOIN pets-lost ON pets.id = pets-lost.id
WHERE pets-lost.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not do where not exists (select * from Lost ...)? Its a sub-select, but I don't see why thats a problem.

Comment: one problem is that e.g. old versions of mysql don't support subselects.

Comment: one other problem, is that subselects are much more slow than joins.

Comment: one additional problem is that the question asked how to do it without sub selects

Comment: @mat: "subselects are much more slow than joins" not always true.  You need to actually measure.  Some subselects are optimized into joins.

Comment: The better the query optimizer, the less it matters.  However, some are dumb indeed.